# Драйвер для убунту

Tags: ubuntu

Как узнать версию сетевой карты и как установить (обновить) для нее драйвер? Работа полностью под убунтой 11,10

Answer (score 1):

Для определения оборудывания в Linux:

- dmesg
- lspci
- lsusb
- lshw

Просмотр содержимого /proc

В Иксах:

- hwbrouser
- [hardinfo](http://wiki.hardinfo.org/HomePage)

Так же lshw-gtk, все можно посмотреть в репах командой:

```
aptitude search lshw-gtk или hardinfo
```

[Дровишки:)](http://www.linux-drivers.org/) можно посмотреть тут.